# consultar e somar resultado do BD

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho uma tabela (`dia`) que recebe os dados ao decorrer dos dias:

```
(id, dia, cliente, func, servicos, valor, produtos, valorp, fdp)
(1, 2018-11-01, cliente1, func1, servicos1, 0++, produto1, 0++, D ou C)
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta referente ao dia atual (`$date`), separar Serviços pagos (`fdp`) com `D` (dinheiro) ou `C` (Cartão) e somá-los.

Teria alguma forma simples de fazer essa soma? Sem pesar muito o código porque terei que fazer uma segunda consulta pra fazer o mesmo com Produtos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, estou entendo que vc quer fazer uma consulta SQL. Se for este o caso segue os passos com um banco de dados exemplo que criei para vc testar, neste caso estou usando MySQL então em outro banco a sintaxe pode mudar um pouco.

1) Criação da tabela no banco de dados

```
CREATE TABLE `DATA` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DIA` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CLIENTE` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `FUNCIONARIO` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `SERVICO` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `VALOR` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRODUTOS` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `VALORRP` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FDP` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2) Populando a tabela

```
INSERT INTO `DATA` (`ID`, `DIA`, `CLIENTE`, `FUNCIONARIO`, `SERVICO`, `VALOR`, `PRODUTOS`, `VALORRP`, `FDP`)
VALUES
    (1,'10/11/2018','CLIENTE1','FUNCIONARIO1','SERVICO1',22.00,'PRODUTOS1',25.00,'D'),
    (2,'11/11/2018','CLIENTE2','FUNCIONARIO1','SERVICO1',10.00,'PRODUTOS2',16.00,'D'),
    (3,'11/11/2018','CLIENTE2','FUNCIONARIO1','SERVICO1',22.00,'PRODUTOS2',12.00,'C'),
    (4,'11/11/2018','CLIENTE2','FUNCIONARIO2','SERVICO2',11.00,'PRODUTOS2',16.00,'D'),
    (5,'11/11/2018','CLIENTE1','FUNCIONARIO1','SERVICO2',11.00,'PRODUTOS2',13.00,'D'),
    (6,'11/11/2018','CLIENTE2','FUNCIONARIO2','SERVICO2',11.00,'PRODUTOS2',16.00,'D'),
    (7,'12/11/2018','CLIENTE1','FUNCIONARIO1','SERVICO2',11.00,'PRODUTOS2',13.00,'D'),
    (8,'12/11/2018','CLIENTE2','FUNCIONARIO2','SERVICO2',13.00,'PRODUTOS2',12.00,'C'),
    (9,'13/11/2018','CLIENTE2','FUNCIONARIO2','SERVICO2',11.00,'PRODUTOS2',16.00,'D'),
    (10,'13/11/2018','CLIENTE2','FUNCIONARIO1','SERVICO2',10.00,'PRODUTOS2',13.00,'D');
```

3) Realizando a consulta

```
    SELECT
    DIA,
    SUM(case when FDP = 'D' then VALOR else 0 end) AS DEBITO,
    SUM(case when FDP = 'C' then VALOR else 0 end) AS CREDITO,
    (SUM(case when FDP = 'D' then VALOR else 0 end) + SUM(case when FDP = 'C' then VALOR else 0 end) ) as TOTAL
    FROM DATA WHERE DIA = '11/11/2018' GROUP BY DIA
```

4) Resultado da consulta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso vc queira pesquisar somente o dia atual então o where ficarás DIA = CURDATE()